# what is the use beforeSend function in (Jquery) Ajax

Tags: rest, jquery, jersey

What is the use of `beforeSend` Function in jQuery Ajax?

How to use the jQuery function?

I am Using jQuery 1.6.0, and Using Jersey API (Restful Web services) on Server Side.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url:ajax_url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",                    
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic "+ btoa(username + ':' + password)); 
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert(data.groups);
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
        console.log("readyState:"+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status)
        alert(xhr.responseText)
        alert("Service is not Available , Try it after Some time");
    }
});
```

Java Code :

```
@GET

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String authCheck(){

return "({"groups": "success"})";

}
```

Whenever I am sending for authentication I am getting success response.

How to use `beforeSend` function and does we need to do any thing on server side?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to do the basic authentication on client side using Jquery Ajax call. Some one suggested me, use beforeSend function to do that. I want to understand How to use beforeSend function in Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `beforeSend()` is used to do some stuff before actually send AJAX request like set Custom header and etc...

but your need is different that you want to authenticate user before your ajax call than

create one another function which give you User is authenticated or Not in Response
suppose this function is `checkAuth();`

so use

```
type: "GET",
    url:ajax_url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",                    
    async: false,
    beforeSend:checkAuth,

.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, If authentications fails then I want to stop the ajax call, is it possible?    
Ex: checkAuth(userid, Password){
          authentication fails;
       }
I want to stop the ajax call and show the error message to user

Comment: using setRequestHeader(), we will set the custom headers data. How to use those data on server side.

Comment: @GET
   public String yourFunction(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String Authorization) {
   ...
   }